# TFS2013 edit iteration name causes TF400483 error on TFS team website

Tags: tfs

Are we able to change an iteration name once work items are created using that name?  After editing the iteration name I get the following error when navigating to the TFS project site 'Work' page:

```
TF400483: You cannot view information for the following iteration: <the old iteration name was here>. The iteration path might have been deleted, or it might not be selected for your team. 

To view your backlog available iterations, click here.
```

If I edit back to the previous name, everything resolves out, so it's not a disaster, but this problem suggests I'm missing something key about editing iterations.

I do have Power Tools installed and followed:

```
Team > Team Project Settings > Work Item Iterations
```

which took me to the TFS portal **Control Panel > 'collection' > 'project'** where I edited the iteration.  I assumed the system would 'ripple' the change through all the work items, but apparently not.

So am I simply trying to do something that's not possible, or am I trying to do something possible but doing it the wrong way?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an annoyance of versions prior to TFS 2015. The problem here is that you have a query which is hard coded to look at the iteration by name. In TFS 2015, we gained the **@CurrentIteration** token so this is no longer a problem. In your case, you need to find and edit any work item queries which are referencing the old name. TFS does **not** update these queries when you rename.

One way around it in versions prior to TFS 2015 is to create a **Current** Iteration and have all of your queries point to **Current**. Then you can simply drag and drop into/from **Current** and you can rename in here to your hearts content. Just be wary of having multiple iterations under **Current**. e.g.

Do this:

```
-Team
    -Release 1.1
        -Current
            -Sprint 1
        -Sprint 2
```

Instead of this:

```
-Team
    -Release 1.1
        -Sprint 1
        -Sprint 2
```